# CyberSource rejects orders from certain amount ranges with code 203

Tags: php, soap, payment-gateway, payment-processing, cybersource

I'm having a problem with CyberSource (test environment).
The thing is that I'm sending Auth requests for orders with total amounts **>=$1000**.
Auth reply comes as:

```
[ccAuthReply] => stdClass Object
(
     [reasonCode] => 203
     [avsCode] => 1
     [processorResponse] => 303 //sometimes with 100 code
)
```

I've made successful transactions with amounts **< $1000** and **>=$12 000** , which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

From [Cybersource](https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/When-I-submit-credit-card-transactions-totaling-between-1000-and-5000-to-your-test-environment-they-fail-Why-does-this-happen):

> The CyberSource test environment is set to return errors for order totals between $1000 and $5000. This is intentional to allow users to become familiar with the reply messages returned for various errors and develop error handling methods for the errors generated.